# Django custom management commands as windows scheduled task

Tags: python-3.5, windows-server-2008-r2, django-2.1

I'm trying to run a Django2.1 custom management command from within a python3 virtual environment on a windows server with the task scheduler. The command I've tried work as follows:

```
C:\Users\dev\Programs\Python3\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\dev\Programs\Python3\Scripts\access-api\my_project\manage.py accessapi
```

The script runs just fine if I also execute it as a .bat file but when I try to create a scheduled task and run the .bat script, the task scheduler fails or says it completed but the data that I'm looking to update, doesn't get updated. I managed to find [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/64ejps/windows_task_scheduler_and_python_virtual_env/) about this same issue but it doesn't seem to work as described.

The script itself isn't a pretty one but it works using pyodbc drivers to run queries in from an Access 2010 database and convert to it JSON, then update required records using Django's API in a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

"Actions" Tab in task property use your commands to configure as:

Program script field:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe
```

Add Argumenrs(optional) field:

```
"C:\Users\dev\Programs\Python3\Scripts\access-api\my_project\manage.py" accessapi
```